# Is this the way to implement ObjectDataSource sorting for a POCO?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

I sometimes get the feeling I'm overlooking something when I have to do this much work.

This code successfully sorts one column.  The switch statement will have to be manually built out for additional.

Am I overlooking the "actual/easy" way to do this?

*note*: there seems to be a comment in the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.sortparametername.aspx) saying this isn't possible at all, unless I'm reading that wrong (but it does work, just a pain this way).

*other note*: I use the terms DAC and POCO here with less than full confidence so correct me if it could be better.

**ObjectDataSource +  GridView**:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AppID" HeaderText="AppID" SortExpression="AppID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Timestamp" HeaderText="Timestamp" SortExpression="Timestamp" />
            DataField="Credit" HeaderText="Credit" SortExpression="Credit" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLeads" TypeName="Leads.LeadsContainer" SortParameterName="sortParameter">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Snippet from DAC**:

```
    public List<ILead> GetLeads(string sortParameter)
    {
        List<ILead> leads = new List<ILead>();
        int numLeads = 10;
        Random random = new Random();
        while (leads.Count < numLeads)
        {
            leads.Add(Lead.CreateRandom(random));
        }
        string[] sortExpressions = sortParameter.Split(',');
        if (sortExpressions.Length > 0)
        {
            string sortExpression = sortExpressions[0];
            string[] sortInfos = sortExpression.Split(' ');
            string sortField = sortInfos[0];
            string sortDirection = (sortInfos.Length == 1 ? "ASC" : "DESC");
            switch (sortField)
            {
                case "Timestamp":
                    switch (sortDirection)
                    {
                        case "ASC":
                            leads = leads.OrderBy(c => c.Timestamp).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "DESC":
                            leads = leads.OrderByDescending(c => c.Timestamp).ToList();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return leads;
    }
```

**POCO (interface)**:

```
public interface ILead
{
    string AppID { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
    DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    string CDNumber { get; set; }
    string IP { get; set; }
    string ESourceID { get; set; }
    string State { get; set; }
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    bool IsVetran { get; set; }
    string Credit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty much like all the ASP.NET WinForms code I've ever seen that has had to do this. Never been easy.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer - ASP.NET WinForms? That would be a neat trick.

Comment: @M.Babcock Fingers moving faster than brain. WEBforms, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Dynamic linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). This can make a linq query taking string as parameter, however the string has to prepared.

The string can be be used for anything, filtering depending on the conditions, sorting, between one value and another.